# Where is this mural?

Tags: canada, buses, identify-this, greyhound

I have been across Canada with the Greyhound bus a couple years ago. I remember taking this picture in the Prairies (Alberta or Saskatchewan) but I don't know in which town.

[image: mural]

In which town is this mural?

Note: I posted it [on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vincetraveller/11011617223/in/album-72157637972648516/) and indicated multiple conflicting places, but I have no idea where it really is.

Comment: @pnuts yes, what makes you doubt it?

Comment: Haha indeed it's funny. A hotel also apparently used that picture. For my defense, if you follow the Flickr link it says I took this picture in July 2011, while the website supposedly dates from 2013 or later.

Comment: And I located it in Medicine Hat. Which one is true? Is one of them even accurate? I'm really not sure. The "Swift current" search on Google image does not show any other picture of this building so I  have doubts it is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of sleuthing gives me [Swift Current, Saskatchewan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_Current).

Based on [this blog post](http://morleymoose.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/day-174-and-175-herbert-to-swift.html) and someone using what seems to be a crop of your photo on [this page](http://www.moveit.ca/saskatchewan/swift-current/) and [this page](http://www.carscredit.ca/saskatchewan/swift-current-car-loans.php).

Note that the blog post above is not OP's.

User pnuts went further and found [the actual location](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@50.2831897,-107.8053678,3a,75y,238.72h,92.95t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1spiMUr9H4udeFkv2_jeIung!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DpiMUr9H4udeFkv2_jeIung%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D270.42123%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656) in Swift Current.